# How to bind a static directory to an angular 4 application

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to bind a whole directory of static files to an angular 4 application? The intention behind this is to get the content of this directory dynamically to see what files are inside the directory.

I know it´s possible to bind a directory to the application using

```
"assets": [
    "favicon.ico",
    "assets",
    {
      "glob": "**/*.svg",
      "input": "../node_modules/@myModule/assets/images",
      "output": "./assets/images"
    }
  ]
```

With the above approach, you can only address the files by calling them explicit e.g. `HOST:PORT/assets/images/myImage.svg`

So the question is:
**Is it possible to bind an directory, so I´m able to call `HOST:PORT/assets/images` and get all containing files dynamically?**

If not:
**Is there another way to get all files dynamically from my static directory in my Angular app?**

Comment: Not clientside-only.

Comment: did you just try to remove the "glob": "**/*.svg", part or changing it to "glob": "**/*.*" ?

Comment: @PierreMallet If I try this approach, neither the direct call nor the dynamic call will work.

Comment: @Zlatko Not even using JS?

Comment: Well, not client-side JS. You basically want a directory listing. JavaScript (the one on the client) can't even access local files (on the user's computer), let alone remote ones, on the server. But you may have other options, depending on _what_ are you trying to do. What _are_ you trying to do?

Comment: @Zlatko Inside my angular application, there is a directory containing all `svg` icons used in the app. I want to create a separate component listing these icons and display them dynamically. I don´t want do reference each icon on it´s own since there are more than 50 of them and the names are changing from then and now. Thats why I am trying to read the containing files dynamically. So in my understanding the files I´m trying to fetch should be accessible since the app also uses them on the GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: no.

The longer answer, not right out of the box. The icons (as mentioned in your comments) are accessible, but not listable. So you can create a list of icons on build time, something like this.

Add an enumerator script in your `tools` or similar directory. E.g.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readdirSync = fs.readdirSync;
const writeFileSync = fs.writeFileSync;
const files = readdirSync('src/assets/svg');
const jsonObj = { files };
writeFileSync('src/app/svg-files.json', JSON.stringify(jsonObj, null, 2));
```

Run that script in your package.json. E.g.

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "listSvgs": "node tools/list-svgs"
}
```

Run that script in your `build` pipeline in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  - "build": "ng build -p",
  + "build": "npm run listSvgs && ng build -p"
  ...
}
```

(You'll know, I guess, which line goes out and which comes in its place.)

Generate the files first time manually, so you don't forget (`npm run listSvgs`).

Add a service to fetch the files in your Angular code:

```
@Injectable
export class SVGListingService {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
    getSVGs() {
        return this.http.get('svg-files.json');
    }
}
```

You should be able to use it, remember to rerun it when you add svgs. And adjust paths.

Comment: Thank you for this nice workaround! Can you please tell me what type of file you are using for the enumeration script in the beginning?

Comment: Just a regular JavaScript (Node.js) script. In fact, you have to name it and match with that second step, e.g. if you name it 'list-svgs.js', then cool, if you rename it, update your scripts path.

Comment: When putting the code inside an list-svg.js file and running npm run listSvgs, i get the following error `(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { const { readdirSync, writeFileSync } from 'fs';
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Missing initializer in destructuring declaration`

Comment: Oh, you seem to be putting this through webpack or something? It's a simple node script, not placed together with your sources. Put it outside of your other files. What do you get when you run it directly? `node list-svgs.js`?

Comment: Yeah, I´m working with webpack and npm. If I try to run it with `node list-svgs.js` the same error occurs. Even with a node runtime inside WebStorm the exact same error occurs

Comment: @JohnDizzle I updated the script. If it doesn't work again, can you simply open Node REPL (type "node" on command line") and paste the contents there?

Comment: The creation of the list is working properly with the updating script, I´m just struggeling to get the list inside my service/component. `HTTP 404` is shown even if the list is there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165428/discussion-between-zlatko-and-johndizzle).